# PHP Update array index/key

Tags: php

I got an array and would like to convert its array keys from camel case to underscore case. How this could be done?

```
$before = ['ThisIsATest' => 'Something', 'cheeseCake' => 'Something else'];
$after = ['this_is_a_test' => 'Something', 'cheese_cake' => 'Something else'];
```

I primarily would like to know how to update array keys!

---

**Based on your input i created the following two functions:**

```
function camelToUnderscore($string)
{
    if (is_numeric($string)) {
        return $string;
    }

    preg_match_all('!([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?=$|[A-Z][a-z0-9])|[A-Za-z][a-z0-9]+)!', $string, $matches);
    $ret = $matches[0];
    foreach ($ret as &$match) {
        $match = $match == strtoupper($match) ? strtolower($match) : lcfirst($match);
    }

    return implode('_', $ret);
}

function keysCamelToUnderscore(array $array)
{
    $newArray = [];

    foreach ($array AS $key => $value) {

        if (!is_array($value)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
            $newArray[camelToUnderscore($key)] = $value;
        } else {
            unset($array[$key]);
            $newArray[camelToUnderscore($key)] = keysCamelToUnderscore($value);
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's primarily about updating array keys.

Comment: To change an array key, you have to create a duplicate value entry with the new key, then unset the old key

Comment: An alternative would be to use array_flip(), update the values, then array_flip() again

Comment: Or possibly to use something like array_combine() with array_keys() and array_values(), modifying the keyset before combining back again

Comment: @MarkBaker I have arrays in the area of 20 to 50 indexes... Would you say performance does not need to be considered?

Comment: `$before = ['ThisIsATest' => 'Something', 'cheeseCake' => 'Something else'];

$before = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function ($value) {
            return strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<!^)[A-Z]/', '_$0', $value));
        },
        array_keys($before)
    ),
    $before
);

var_dump($before);`